# VSTO pre-populated template available via AddIn

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel, vsto, excel-addins, excel-template

I'm new to VSTO - while within Excel, we would like the user to click on an Excel AddIn icon, to get a template of headings, formulas, colours/fonts, etc.  Is it best to create this via a VS2010 "Excel Template" or "Excel AddIn" project?

Note that the populated template will need to contain dropdowns filled with data from the database (which will be transferred thru a WCF service).  Also the Excel VSTO client will need to push data back to the WCF service for database updates

Comment: If I understand correctly, you envision this as one unique template, is that right? i.e you want to display database data into a worksheet that has a pre-defined format, and push back edits to the database if needed?

Comment: Yes Mathias - that is correct - the user will see a template with headings/formulas/colours populated with fresh data from the database - s/he then edits certain unprotected cells, pushes a submit button on the sheet and updates are sent back (via WCF) and persisted on the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the payload involved in moving a template down to the client, we decided to send the data required to populate the client down the wire (JSON, compressed via GZip) and let the client receive and interpret the data and populate the Excel sheet as required (dynamic created controls, cell population, etc via VSTO)